# Create topic for category with CRUD resource concept of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I have categories in `Route::resource('category', 'CategoriesController');`

And each category have topics, topics under 
`Route::resource('topic', 'TopicsController');`.

In each category are topics.

So we can go to specific category, e.g. `/category/Games` and here we have topics about games, e.g. topic `WoW`. This topic is under `/topic/WoW`. All with usage of method `show`

And now my problem

Let's assume user wants to create new topic, he is in `/category/Games`, clicks button `New Topic` that points to `/topics/create`... To give users ability to create new topic I assume that I should use `create` method of this resource `TopicsController` according to CRUD resource metodology

But

If I do this it will be like `/topic/create`

So how do I next will know to which `Category` this topic has to go?

If I had like `/category/WoW/topic/create` Then I could take section name, I would have it.

But as I think according to this CRUD metodology properly I should place this as I said in `create` method of resource `TopicsController`, but what about then with knowing to which category user wanted it to  go? I do not know how I properly should handle this situation

Comment: for related data or entity you ned to pass the related data to your API. For example if topic does not exist without category then at the time of creation of topic you need to pass your category unique name or something that makes your category unique and easy to pick.

Comment: You can give dropdown of categories in your form and user will select a category whichever they wanted.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik this is not an option. It's about forum categories, threads and posts :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in this [Laracast discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/nested-resources-controllers-structure), you can use dot syntax to specify nested models inside your resource route. In your case, this would mean in `/routes/routes.php` (in Laravel 5.3+) or in `app/Http/routes.php` (in Laravel 5.0 - 5.2) :

```
Route::resource('category.topic', 'CategoryTopicController');
```

This will need you to create a resource controller for this use. In command line :

```
php artisan make:controller CategoryTopicController --resource
```

`--resource` automatically creates the necessary methods to get quickly started, but you can write them manually (make sure they go along with what the `php artisan route:list` specify).

Eventually you come up to those routes :

- GET `/category/{category}/topic` along with the method `index()`
- GET `/category/{category}/topic/{topic}` along with the method `show($id)`
- POST `/category/{category}/topic` along with the method `store(Request $request)`
- PUT `/category/{category}/topic/{topic}` along with the method `update(Request $request, $id)`
- DELETE `/category/{category}/topic/{topic}` along with the method `destroy($id)`

Even if Laravel created those method with `$id` parameter, you can consider it a string (the best is a slug that you can include in your routes, like `/category/wow/topic/create` or `/category/rainbow-6/topic/create`).

Dont forget to create the models if not done : `php artisan make:model Category --table=category && php artisan make:model Topic --table=topic`.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

Since may 2017, if you want to get rid of additionnal routes `edit` and `create` (which are only routes for displaying forms to make a `store` or an `update` to your resource), you can use `Route::apiResource` instead of `Route::resource` (see [this pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19347), an information coming from [this laraveldaily post](http://laraveldaily.com/resource-controllers-api-remove-createedit-methods/)).